# Mysql/MariaDB search thru AES Encrypted data

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb, sql-like, having

I have a table with aes encrypted data in it and wanted to search thru it with a select statement with a `LIKE` in it. Now since I have to decrypt it first I am using the `HAVING` but for some reason the `LIKE` is case sensitive. I have tried putter `LOWER()` around the data but that doesn't seem to be changing the situation.

```
SELECT fd.id, AES_DECRYPT(fd.data, 'mysecretkey') AS data
FROM field_data fd
HAVING LOWER(data) LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a collation that is case insensitive

> ```
> CREATE TABLE field_data (id int,data  BLOB)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO field_data
> VALUES (1,AES_ENCRYPT('testmedata', UNHEX(SHA2('My secret passphrase',512))))
> ,(2,AES_ENCRYPT('TESTmedata', UNHEX(SHA2('My secret passphrase',512))));
> ```

> ```
> SELECT fd.id, AES_DECRYPT(fd.data, UNHEX(SHA2('My secret passphrase',512))) AS decdata
> FROM field_data fd
> HAVING decdata  LIKE '%test%' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
> ```

> ```
> id | decdata   
> -: | :---------
>  1 | testmedata
>  2 | TESTmedata
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e1ec3069629bef8fdae531536468b47)*

Comment: Thanks this is working exactly as i wanted! :D

Comment: May I ask why the blob instead of a text/longtext?

Comment: The online system reported an error When it is a text as AES_ENCRYPT returns a binary

Comment: Note: You can use column type `TEXT`  and use `TO_BASE64()` with `FROM_BASE64()` to make encrypted binary as string but in the end, when you search with `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64())` it will becomes binary and must use with `CALLATE xxx` anyway. Up voted for this answer.